# Can I take the cover off my fusebox to attach an energy monitor?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electric-motor

I have bought an Energy Monitor to track our electricity usage (hard times...).  I now need to put the sensor on one of the cables either next to the fusebox or the meter.  Unfortunately I cannot access any cables surrounding the meter as it is all secured either behind cable protectors or the walls in our flat's lobby.  That leaves me with access to only the fusebox within our flat.

My question is this, I cannot see any cables surrounding the fusebox but I can see two screws on the cover - is it safe to take these off to see if I can access a cable inside to place the sensor around?

I hope this is the right place to ask.  We have lived here for quite a few years but nobody seems to understand our boiler and I would like to track our energy usage as we are on Economy 10 but seem to be using 70% On-peak energy and only 30% Off-peak..even with an economy 10 boiler and the dishwasher/dryer/washing machine etc going on during the off-peak times..  It's almost £200 a month for 2 people in a small flat and we are energy conscious.

Comment: You may need to drain your boiler to remove sediment ( assuming it is what we in the USA would call a water heater ). I don't know how your boiler "knows" when it should heat up, but it could also be a wiring problem or a clock problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would find some way to attach the measuring clamp around the live feed near the meter.

My house, as many do, has an external wall-box flush-mounted into an external brick wall. It used to look like this

[image]
[image]

Mine is a bit unusual in that the supply is three-phase rather than the more usual single-phase but the general layout is the same.

- At bottom left is the incoming unmetered supply terminated at 100A (230V) supply fuses. You are not permitted to touch these.
- Neutral and Live (usually one but three in my case) wires feed the meter.
- You can see the after-meter live wire (marked with red tape) disappears off into the wall at top left.

There should always be enough room to attach a current sensing clamp over that wire. The wires are very stiff but you should be able to move them enough to attach a typical clamp around the live wire safely.

Inside my house, on the opposite side of the same wall, is a separate wall-mounted "consumer unit" inside a cupboard. These are often called a fuse-box although these distribution panels now contain miniature circuit breakers (MCBs) rather than fuses.

[image]

There is no way to attach a current sensing clamp here and I would advise against opening up the panel to find the incoming live feed. You would need to isolate the supply into the building and there is no facility for householders to do this - I believe you are expected to contact the electricity supply company if you need to isolate anything before the main switch on the consumer unit.

The current-sense clamps supplied with energy monitors are intended to be used in the exterior meter box.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll take a photo of our meter tomorrow (it's a bit dark know and I have no appropriate torch) - our consumer unit (thanks for the correction) does look like the above so I'll hold off touching that.  Unfortunately I couldn't see any cables near our meter's but I'll have a proper look tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

Before unscrewing any screws on the fusebox, turn off the electricity!

But even before doing that make sure you've got a torch handy, 'cos fuseboxes are invariably in dark places (a head-torch is useful).

Comment: This really belongs as a comment, as it does not directly answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If you at all worried about making such a connection it would be best to call a qualified electrician, or power box expert (or what ever you might call that type of person on your side of the pond).

Placing an amp clamp over the single main insulated wire might be enough with possibly just some small error amount.